# How to implement multiple datasource without setPackagesToScan and without persistence.xml

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I'm looking for a way to assign entities to different datasource from determined classes rather than packages in Spring Data Jpa.

Because The entities which belong to different datasource are in the same packages, I cannot use setPackagesToScan to sperate them with the following code. I need a function like setClassesToScan.

```
@Bean("HospEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(hospDataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(new Properties());
        \\entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("hquery");

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }
```

I tried the following code and I don't sure it is intent for my purpose.

```
        DefaultPersistenceUnitManager persistenceUnitManager = new DefaultPersistenceUnitManager();
        persistenceUnitManager.setManagedTypes(PersistenceManagedTypes.of(Greeting.class.getCanonicalName()));
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitManager(persistenceUnitManager);
```

And I got an error: No persistence units parsed from {classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml}.
I don't expect to have perisitence.xml in my project.